# How to save response path keys into variable

Tags: python, json

I have a json response where path key to value is like `response['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']`
How I can save `['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4']` into same variable for reuse it next code?
Like `response[saved_path]` or some other variant

Example. Has a method:

`def post_new_user
   response = some_code
   return json.loads(response.text)`

As a result I am getting a json response. And there are to much data in it. Sometime required data are in deep of it.

Comment: Use a list perhaps `['key1','key2','key3','key4']`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What are you trying to do?

Comment: looks like you need to flatten your json

Comment: I just want to specify path of key into one variable and then just reuse it. Just do not type response['key1']['key2']['key3']['key4'] every time. And also do not need to paste this path into return method.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be optimal, but I usually write a helper function for such tasks:

```py
def get_by_path(d, path):
    # recursive helper function to access the element at the desired path
    def get(d,l):
        if len(l) == 0:
            return d
        else:
            return get(d[l[0]], l[1:])
    # split the path to generate the list
    return get(d, path.split('/'))
```

Then, assuming `jsondict` is your parsed json object, you can access the desired path using the above function:

```
jsondict = {'abc': { 'def': { 'ghi': 42 } } }
print( get_by_path(jsondict, 'abc/def/ghi') )
```